# How to use the CCTimer class in Cocos2d android?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I want to use `CCTimer` class for the Timer but I can't sort out. After I use to manually create a function for this but it seems not effective .

```
protected GameLayer(ccColor4B color)
{
    super(color);

            schedule(new UpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void update(float d) {
            countTime(d);
        }
      },0.99f);

}

public void countTime(float scr) {
    if(_label != null){
        this.removeChild(_label,true);
    }
    j=j-(int)scr;

    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    _label = CCLabel.makeLabel("Time Left :" + j, "Verdana", 20);
    _label.setColor(ccColor3B.ccGREEN);
    _label.setPosition(155f, winSize.height - 15);
    addChild(_label);

    if(j<=0){
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();
    }

}
```

it run from 1 to the the point which i want to stop ... !!!

what should i do to use the `CCTimer` class to resolve this problem ?

Comment: CCTimer class is available but haven't any methods.

Comment: there is any other way to call or handle the CCTimer...!!!!

Comment: I have done this problem through CCLabelAtlas class but if someone have the solution through CCTimer than give your contribution to fix this problem ...!!!!

Comment: I am still not find the perfect solution through CCTimer class.... does anyone know . how to fix this one ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCTimer is available but I haven't tried this earlier but you can do this thing through Timer class :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask(){
public void run() {
    updateTimeLabel();
}




public void updateTimeLabel() {
        float time += 1;
        String string = CCFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", (int)(time /60) , (int)time % 60 );
        CCBitmapFontAtlas timerLabel = (CCBitmapFontAtlas) getChildByTag(TIMER_LABEL_TAG) ;
        timerLabel.setString(string);
}
```

Comment: I told you earlier that I haven't work on it. Sorry about that ,through this you can complete your work ..